# Hide a leaflet angular map on initial load

Tags: css, angular, typescript, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

i have a map for which following css is used.When the page loads i want the map to be hidden and get loaded only after a button is pressed

From the console i used the following and it was working and it made the map hidden

```
    document.getElementsByClassName('DemoMap')[0]).style.height="0px";
```

But from the typescript code

```
    (<HTMLElement>document.getElementsByClassName('DemoMap')[0]).style.height="0px";
```

i am getting a runtime error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

```
.DemoMap {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 600px);
  height: calc(100% - 400px);
  top: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a flag 
`isMapVisible = false;`

In your markup use `[style.display]` to configure the flag's state:

```
<div
  style="height: 90vh;"
  [style.display]="isMapVisible ? 'block' : 'none'"
  leaflet
  [leafletOptions]="options"
></div>

<button (click)="showMap()">Show map</button>
```

Use a button to change the boolean's state to true using an event listener:

```
showMap() {
    this.isMapVisible = true;
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hide-a-leaflet-angular-map-on-initial-load-gwmm2?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:505-550)